# SSH into machine then connect TCP socket

Tags: c#, tcpclient

I am able to:

```
ssh -p 8811 myuser@74.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Then from within that machine, can run a program that successfully establishes socket connection at 10.xx.xxx.xxx on port 32060.

I am trying to convert it to a local C# program that does the ssh + socket connection without having to keep the ssh open on my terminal, so I can just run the program.

It is able to successfully ssh in, then ping the 10.xx.xxx.xxx address, but cannot establish the socket connection. Am I missing a step?

```
using (var client = new SshClient("74.xxx.xxx.xxx", 8811, "myuser", privatekey))
{

    client.Connect();

    string host = "10.xx.xxx.xxx";
    int port = 32060;

    if (client.IsConnected)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ssh connected");
        SshCommand cmd = client.CreateCommand($"ping -c 3 {host}");
        cmd.Execute();
        Console.WriteLine(cmd.Result); // successfully pings 10.xx.xxx.xxx

        TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient();
        tcpClient.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(host), port));
        Console.WriteLine("tcp connected"); // fails, times out when trying 10.xx.xxx.xxx:32060

    }

    client.Disconnect();
}
```

Comment: Your `TcpClient` doesn't interact in any way with the open SSH connection

Comment: Do a web search for "ssh over tcp"

Answer (score -1):

I was able to get this to work using a package called Chilkat `socket.UseSsh()`: https://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/csSocketRef.html#method91

```
string sshUsername = "myuser";
string sshHostname = "74.xxx.xxx.xxx";
int sshPort = 8811;

string socketHostname = "10.xx.xxx.xxx";
int socketPort = 32060;

// === SSH ===
Chilkat.Ssh ssh = new Chilkat.Ssh();

Chilkat.SshKey sshkey = new Chilkat.SshKey();
sshkey.FromOpenSshPrivateKey(@"xxx");

bool success = ssh.Connect(sshHostname, sshPort);
if (success != true)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ssh.LastErrorText);
    return;
}

success = ssh.AuthenticatePk(sshUsername, sshkey);
if (success != true)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ssh.LastErrorText);
    return;
}

// === Socket ===
Chilkat.Socket socket = new Chilkat.Socket();

success = socket.UseSsh(ssh);
if (success != true)
{
    Console.WriteLine(socket.LastErrorText);
    return;
}

bool useTls = false;
int maxWaitMillisec = 20000;
success = socket.Connect(socketHostname, socketPort, useTls, maxWaitMillisec);
if (success != true)
{
    Console.WriteLine(socket.LastErrorText);
    return;
}
```

Comment: The chilllkat library is a commercial, proprietary third-party-product. While some classes are free, your example uses classes that require a paid license bundle. Not really a good example for a question that is based on pure C#. If the whole question would be in the context of the chillkat lib, I wouldn't complain. But as its generic c# context, the solution should be in the same (open/free) context.